# sending data to server - but server gets blank data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, webserver

I am trying to send data to the server.When i am sending the request it send to the server but server get its blank.I am not getting why it is happend.Please help me to solve this.

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username",@"password",@"email",@"fullname",@"phone",@"status",nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test",@"123456",@"test999@test.com",@"name",@"234566343",@"1",nil];


NSDictionary *questionDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:questionDict];
NSString *jsonRequest = [jsonDict JSONRepresentation];

RequestHandler *handler = [[RequestHandler alloc] init];
handler.method = @"POST";
handler.delegate = self;

   NSLog(@"JSOnRequest -- %@",jsonRequest);
handler.postData = jsonRequest;
handler.requestName = @"registration";
handler.URL =@"http://demo.keshavinfotech.com/edv/user_register.php?";

[handler startRequest];
[handler release];

- (void)startRequest 

{
 NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mRequestURL]];//NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL

                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad

                                                       timeoutInterval:mTimeOut];



    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [mPostData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


    [request setHTTPBody:[mPostData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    self.connection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];

}
```

is it server encoding-decoding problem or something else???

Answer (score 1):

I call to server with following parameters,

```
WebserviceCall[622:f803] {
    email = "test999@test.com";
    fullname = name;
    password = 123456;
    phone = 234566343;
    status = 1;
    username = test;
}
```

Then Response give to me like following wise.

```
{"responseData":{"result":"failed","msg":"Please fill all the required fields"}}
```

Can you pls give the right parameter format to send with that i can check it out.

Comment: i checked in new project so pls give the format which send to server

Comment: server give this response because server gets blank data.there is condition in the server that if all the data are blank then send this response.

Comment: But which format style to receive the server like dictionary or array?

Comment: If i send the data then server side how to trash pls echo into server side
{
    email = "test999@test.com";
    fullname = name;
    password = 123456;
    phone = 234566343;
    status = 1;
    username = test;
}

Comment: if i send data with URL then is there any possibility of app rejection in app store.??

Comment: but get method have some limitation

Comment: Get method has maximum length restricted to 256 characters as it is sent appended with the URL, but the Post method hasn't.

Comment: And no any security for the data access

Comment: Okay i will check it out but when the request sent to server that time you need to return the some dictionary or array to client that's mean till now is ok but just return the response when url is okay
that's slove your problem 100%

Comment: For Checking that type of the response and etc for that you use the add-on of firefox which name is poster for that you got more idea about the response and request

Comment: Now i receive the data but change that values like
{"responseData":{"result":"true","msg":"successful"}}

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this:

```
//form you request like you did (I think it's ok), then

NSData *postData = jsonRequest;

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[urlRequest setURL:@"http://demo.keshavinfotech.com/edv/user_register.php?"];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"charset"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
[urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:60.0];//or whatever interval you prefer

NSURLConnection *tmpConn = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self] autorelease];
self.connectionProperty = tmpConn;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.I have tried this.But its not working for me. :(